# Sender's email is invalid in Sitecore EXM

Tags: exm

I have successfully configured Email cloud service in our environment by testing the connection of the Email manage root.

But upon testing by sending the email, I wasn't able to send an email and this issue has been encountered

> "The sender's email is invalid. This might prevent successful
>   dispatch. Manage sending domains."

Please help :)

Comment: Please see https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/reputation/add_or_edit_a_domain

Comment: Please check the log files for Exm.*.txt and Eds.*.txt and you will get the actual error. Could be related to authentication or login credentials etc

Answer (score 3):

Please make sure that you've configured a sending domain as [explained in the documentation](https://doc.sitecore.net/email_experience_manager/configuring_the_delivery_process/reputation/add_or_edit_a_domain).

One major aspect of email delivery, and making sure your email campaigns end up in the inbox rather than the spam folder, is to establish a good sender reputation.

With the EXM Email Cloud provider, you don't need to worry about establishing a reputation, but you do need to configure a sending domain i.e. the domain corresponding to the FROM address you will be using.

The documentation walks you through how do configure the sending domain, but it's worth noting here that you will need access to add a DNS entry in order to set up a DKIM record.

As a side note, you do not need to set up SPF for your domain, as the return-path of the emails sent using the Email Cloud provider is "spe.sitecoremail.com".

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issue.
So if the solution with the post by Jacob Nielsen doesn't work for you that means you are more likely to be running multilanguage instance.
Therefore please do check in General tab in Senders Details section the field **From Email** contains the same value across all languages you have this template designed for, we had English general was having youremail.com. 
Unfortunately EXM doesn't state what email its trying to parse when stating the **sender email is invalid**. But this was the case in our issue, but definitely do check **Administration -> Domains** so the domain name is present from one you are sending an email and that DKIM is checked as green.